# Java - Can anyone explain this permutation code for me?

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

```
public  static void perm(String str) { 
   perm1(str,"");
}

private static void perm1(String str, String prefix) {
    int n = str.length();

    if (n == 0) StdOut.println(prefix);
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
           String rem = str.substring(0,i) + str.substring(i+1);
           perm1(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

If for example our case is "abc" .. where in the code does this string's length decrease so that we will eventually hit the base case ? I see we are always letting the rem as it is "abc" .. what am I missing ?

Comment: `perm1` is being called recursively with `rem` as the first argument, where `rem` is 1 character shorter than `str`.

Comment: It puts your hair in a perm. At least that's what the interface suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) methods takes substring **exclusively** for endIndex. So for example for i = 1 you will get:

```java
String str = "abc";
String s1 = str.substring(0, 1); // a
String s2 = str.substring(1 + 1); // c
String rem = s1 + s2; // ac
```